# How can I increase the dots per inch of a PDF file?

Tags: gimp, dpi

Does anyone know of a program that can increase the dots per inch (DPI) of a PDF files e.g. from 100dpi when scanned to 200dpi?

GIMP can do this but the issue is that I have PDFs with many pages. GIMP treats each page separately so I end up with 50 individual pages of 200dpi.

Comment: I don't see that you'd be achieving much other than making the file larger.  You'll be changing one black dot into four black dots, each white dot likewise into four dots to increase dpi (*two horizontal+ two vertical*); but I cannot see how this would increase image quality. Unless you re-attach higher resolution (DPI) images creating a new PDF file (assuming it wasn't done via algorithm as you're asking here) .  What you're after will just increase file size without any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several options.

## Option 1:Online websites which you can use to change the DPI.

https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/optimize.aspx

https://pdftojpg.me/

## Option 2: Using `convert` command form ImageMagick

```
convert -density 200 -trim test.pdf -quality 100 test.jpg
```

## Option 3:Using `ghostscript`

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```